# Composer update - Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: updating, composer

when I run a composer update --with-dependencies, I get the following error message:

```
Problem 1
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.0|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.0-alpha1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.0-beta1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.0-beta2|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.0-rc1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.10|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.11|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.12|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.13|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.14|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.15|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.16|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.17|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.2|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.3|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.4|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.5|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.6|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.7|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.8|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.9|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.0|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.0-alpha1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.0-alpha2|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.0-beta1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.0-beta2|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.0-rc1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.2|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.3|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.4|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.5|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.6|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.8.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - remove drupal/drupal dev-master|remove drupal/core 8.7.6
    - Installation request for drupal/drupal dev-master -> satisfiable by drupal/drupal[dev-master].
    - Installation request for drupal/core ~8.6 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.6.0, 8.6.0-alpha1, 8.6.0-beta1, 8.6.0-beta2, 8.6.0-rc1, 8.6.1, 8.6.10, 8.6.11, 8.6.12, 8.6.13, 8.6.14, 8.6.15, 8.6.16, 8.6.17, 8.6.2, 8.6.3, 8.6.4, 8.6.5, 8.6.6, 8.6.7, 8.6.8, 8.6.9, 8.6.x-dev, 8.7.0, 8.7.0-alpha1, 8.7.0-alpha2, 8.7.0-beta1, 8.7.0-beta2, 8.7.0-rc1, 8.7.1, 8.7.2, 8.7.3, 8.7.4, 8.7.5, 8.7.6, 8.7.x-dev, 8.8.x-dev].
```

I have tried:

```
composer clearcache
rm composer.lock
rm -R vendor
rm -R core
```

and then one again:

```
composer update --with-dependencies
```

but still this error!!!

My composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "drupal/drupal",
    "description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0+",
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4",
        "drupal/address": "^1.2",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^1.20",
        "drupal/commerce": "^2.0",
        "drupal/commerce_variation_cart_form": "^1.0",
        "drupal/config_update": "^1.4",
        "drupal/ctools": "^3.0",
        "drupal/devel": "^2.0",
        "drupal/features": "^3.7",
        "drupal/imce": "^1.6",        
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.1",
        "drupal/votingapi": "^3.0",
        "drupal/views_flipped_table" : "^1.2",
        "drupal/field_group": "^1.0",
        "drupal/entity_browser": "^2.0",
        "drupal/shortcode": "^1.0",
        "drupal/dropzonejs": "^2.0@alpha",
        "drupal/embed": "^1.0",
        "drupal/token": "^1.0",
        "drupal/webform": "^5.0",
        "drupal/core": "~8.6",
        "drush/drush": "~9.0"
    },
    "replace": {

    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8"
    },
    "extra": {
        "_readme": [
            "By default Drupal loads the autoloader from ./vendor/autoload.php.",
            "To change the autoloader you can edit ./autoload.php."
        ],
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "core/composer.json"
            ],
            "recurse": false,
            "replace": false,
            "merge-extra": false
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Composer"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
        "post-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess",
        "post-package-install": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
        "post-package-update": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
        "drupal-phpunit-upgrade-check": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::upgradePHPUnit",
        "drupal-phpunit-upgrade": "@composer update phpunit/phpunit --with-dependencies --no-progress",
        "phpcs": "phpcs --standard=core/phpcs.xml.dist --runtime-set installed_paths $($COMPOSER_BINARY config vendor-dir)/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer --",
        "phpcbf": "phpcbf --standard=core/phpcs.xml.dist --runtime-set installed_paths $($COMPOSER_BINARY config vendor-dir)/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer --"
    },
    "repositories": {
        "drupal": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong? Would be grateful for any help?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the Drupal template (https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project)? If so, the command you want is listed on that page as `composer update drupal/core webflo/drupal-core-require-dev "symfony/*" --with-dependencies`

Comment: @Jaypan – The composer.json first line shows drupal/drupal. The composer.json doesn't list the mentioned dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You are using [drupal/drupal](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies#deprecated-drupal-drupalhttps://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies#deprecated-drupal-drupal) that is deprecated (because upgrading is very hard / impossible). After you have fixed the drupal/drupal problem, follow the [normal update instructions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-composer).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the tilde here:
       `"drupal/core": "~8.6",`

From experience I know it is better to pinpoint drupal/core to a certain version. FE `"drupal/core": "8.6.17",` 
This leaves composer with no other choice than going for that version of core.

In case you are using the webflo template you have to run another command:
composer update drupal/core webflo/drupal-core-require-dev --with-dependencies

Or find this package in the composer.json and also pinpoint it to the core version you want.